# Gelfand ring in Bourbaki's exercises

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, banach-algebras

In Bourbaki's General Topology, Chapitre III §6 Exercise 11, they define a *Gelfand Ring* as a topological ring $A$ such that

1. The set $A^*$ ($=A^{-1}$) of invertibles is open.

   The uniform structure induced on $A^*$ by the given one on $A$ is compatible with the group structure.

Of course, the product being continuous, this amounts to only ask that $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ be continuous. 
My question is (as commutativity is not required): 
Is there a link between this notion and the one commonly accepted in commutative algebra? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_ring)

Comment: It looks more like a generalization of Banach algebras —  for which using Gelfand's name seems quite natural.

Comment: Right, note that although these (sometimes noncommutative) Gelfand rings form a category, it is not closed by projective limits. For example, the space of analytic functions $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ over a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a limit of Banach algebras but, in general, not a Gelfand ring (if I am not mistaken).